Jahia demo template set not showing in modules list in Studio
I have a local docker instance running Jahia 8.2. I was able to upload and all modules are running from the Digital demo, including the dx-base-demo-templates. My question is, why I cannot see the template set in Studio view? How can I edit the templates if I cannot see them here? I can see the module in global repository view for example
